# django to show a newly generated html file on each run

Tags: python, django

I have a python script (A.py) that accepts users input via form and runs another python script (B.py). B.py stores html formatted results into a folder named yymmdd.

The file generated by B.py is like "results_hhmmss.html", so every time B.py script is exectued a new has html file is created.

As per my urls.py code below, visiting 127.0.0.1:8888 takes me to home_page. Further, once i submit form using a button in the home_page, the scripts gets executed successfuly, a result files is generated.

Further, how can I render the next webpage to view the generated results_hhmmss.html file?
I am not sure how I can build the urlpatters as everytime the scripts are run, the results file has a new name.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_page),
    # what path or paths to add here ???
]
```

I also wish to see the the relative path of the file results_hhmmss.html (which is in folder yymmdd) in the address bar so i can revisit the same link directly later.

Thanks heaps in advance for taking time to read this post and willingness to help.

I am using python3 and Django version 3.0.7

Edit:
adding my views.py code

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime

from django.views.generic import TemplateView


def welcome_page(request):
    # Purpose: Just display welcome_page.html
    return render(request, 'welcome/welcome_page.html')


    
def generate_results_file_method2(request):

  hhmmss = str(datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S"))
  yyyymmdd = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))

  new_file_name = yyyymmdd + "/results_" + hhmmss + ".html"

  ls_cmd = "pwd; ls -lart | tee " + new_file_name

  output = subprocess.Popen(ls_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

  wait_for_sec = request.POST.get('seconds')
  time.sleep(int(wait_for_sec))

  return render(request, new_file_name)
```

My files structure is below:

Project
welcome
|
|--> 20200627  (this folder contains all "results_(hhmmss).html" files generated by the script.
|--> templates (this folder contains welcome_page.html)
|--> welcome   (this folder contains files urls.py , views.py and other standard django's .py
|--> manage.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:
view.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class PageView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        template_name = "path_to_template/{}.html".format(self.kwargs["page_name"])
        return [template_name]
```

then add changes to you urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pages/<page_name>/', views.PageView.as_view()),
    path('', views.home_page),
]
```

Comment: Hi @AndreyMaslov, thanks, i tried to add your code into mine but being a newbie I am kinda lost and unclear in modifying my code with yours and Amartya's code. Please would you guide me to add your code into mine, I have updated my post with my views.py code if that helps.

Comment: in urls.py replace yours `urlpatterns` with mine. then add in views.py code, that i wrote.

Comment: there is one moment in this code. you should place your new generated files in templates folder

Comment: i tried changing code to save results_hhmmss.html files in tempalts folder instead of yyyymmdd folder. However, i need a path to run your view function code. I dont know how to make the button in the main page to run your view code. I tried adding a path in urls.py in addition to what you asked me but that throws error.

Comment: here is updated urls.py  
  

urlpatterns = [  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    path('pages/<page_name>/', views.PageView.as_view()),  
    path('', views.welcome_page, name='welcome_page'),  
    path('results/', views.andreys_generate_results_file, name='andrey_script')  
]

Comment: sorry code lost its formatting , i am unable to format it for easy reading... `code` or ``` isnt' working

Comment: please refer answer post for my comment for you related to the updated codes.

Comment: wait, i will create project on github for you, you can see it there will post link in few minutes

Comment: https://github.com/rzunimagu/forShashi123 all needed logic in `showfiles`

Comment: thanks heaps @AndreyMaslov, i will run that code in my pc and will respond soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216816/discussion-between-shashi123-and-andrey-maslov).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate model that stores the path of the generated HTML like so

```py
class HTMLGenerated(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=500) # This will store the relative path
```

Then you can use URL parameters in the URL patterns like so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<int:html_id>/reports/', views.report_view)
]
```

The corresponding view can process that something like:

```py
def report_view(request, html_id):
    object = get_object_or_404(HTMLGenerated, pk=html_id)
    # You can access the HTML by
    html = object.path
    # Return the context
    return render(
         request,
         'some_template',
         context = {
             'html': html
         }
```

Comment: Hi @AmartyaGaur, thanks, i tried to add your code into mine but being a newbie I am kinda lost and unclear in modifying my code with yours and Andrey's code. Please would you guide me to add your code into mine, I have updated my post with my views.py code if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

@AndreyMaslov

moving from comments to here to have code formatting, please could you guide and correct me further. Thanks heaps.

here is updated urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pages/<page_name>/', views.PageView.as_view()),
    path('', views.welcome_page, name='welcome_page'),
    path('results/', views.andreys_generate_results_file, name='andrey_script')
]
```

here is views.py code

```py
class PageView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        template_name = "templates/{}.html".format(self.kwargs["page_name"])
        return [template_name]


def andreys_generate_results_file(request):

    hhmmss = str(datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S"))
    yyyymmdd = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))

    # new_file_name = yyyymmdd + "/results_" + hhmmss + ".html"  # actual line, commented for Andrey
    new_file_name = "templates/results_" + hhmmss + ".html"
    ls_cmd = "pwd; ls -lart | tee " + new_file_name

    output = subprocess.Popen(ls_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    wait_for_sec = request.POST.get('seconds')
    time.sleep(int(wait_for_sec))

    return render(request, new_file_name)


def welcome_page(request):
    # Purpose: Just display welcome_page.html
    return render(request, 'welcome/welcome_page.html')
```

here is portion of welcome_page.html form code:

```html
<p>New Form</p>
<hr>
<form action="{% url 'andrey_script' %}" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
    Text:
    <input type="text" name="seconds" required><br><br>
    <button type="submit" value="Run Python Script"> Click to Run Python Script</button>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question, i thought that files generated earlier before user input, need to change my answer, but anyway you can put your file generation logic in get_template_names method and return it there.

Comment: updated git hub, created `form` for user input and place to put your logic to generate new files